# I send structure through socket( c++) by function SENDTO and received by RECVFORM, but always getting some garbage value

Tags: c++, sockets

hey  i am working on a tool NCTUns. and here i am sending structure through sendto function.

my structure -

```
struct agentClientReportStatus{ 
u_int32_t      type;
u_int32_t      nid;
double         timeStamp;
int            flag;
u_int32_t      moreMsgFollowing;
double         x;
double         y;
double         x1;
double         y1;
double         acceleration;
double         speed;
double         direction;
int            TTL;
int           seqNum;
}
```

and functions are -

```
 n = sendto(myUDPsockfd, msg, sizeof(struct agentClientReportStatus), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, len); 
 n = recvfrom(myUDPsockfd, (char *)&msg, sizeof(struct agentClientReportStatus), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &len);
```

in  sending section when i print some value then its give correct output.
but in receiving part i am getting garbage value. is it possible to send it without serialization? and  if not then how i do serialization?

msg are of-    agentClientReportStatus *msg; 
    msg = new agentClientReportStatus;

Comment: You are talking about a structure named `data`, but the function mentions `agentClientReportStatus`. Can you explain ?

Comment: And we need to see what type `msg` is and how it's allocated. Is `msg` of type `data*`?

Comment: The [C++ Middleware Writer](http://webebenezer.net) could help with the serialization.  It supports uint32_t.

Comment: hey sorry for that, my structure name is "agentClientReportStatus".

Answer (score 1):

receiver can have

- different memory alignment
- different endianess ( useful functions to deal with endianess are `htonl`, `ntohl` and alike )
- different size of standard c types

so answer - yes, you should use serialization

Comment: hey sorry for that, my structure name is "agentClientReportStatus".

Comment: i want here broadcasting, and its on a same machine. so serialization is necessary??  @darkmist

Comment: Not serializing is a bad habit to get into. For example, say the next version of your compiler changes the structure padding rules and you recompile the senders but not the receivers.